# SQL Compiling data from Unique batch Identifier across tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an analytics plugin that submits data in JSON. This JSON is taken in PHP and submitted into 6 different tables into a MySQL 5.6 database, each array in the JSON coorelates with a table because some data requires iteration rather than direct call.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "general": {
            "starttime": "2010-92-02 21:21:21",
            "userip": "192.168.1.1",
            "page accessed": "index.php"
        },
        "page": {
            "loadtime": "1.4",
            "clicks": "5",
            "pageslist": {
                "index.php": {
                    "access time": "5"
                },
                "example.php": {
                    "access time": "1"
                },
                "contact.php": {
                    "access time": "2"
                }
            }
        },
        "userdetails": {
            "userid": "123",
            "likespie": true,
            "usersliked": {
                "george": {
                    "thinksiscool": true,
                    "last poked": "5"
                },
                "debra": {
                    "thinksiscool": false,
                    "last poked": "1000"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is put this data into seperate tables, with each row having a uniqueID that the other rows from this data share, effectively being an identifier for that 'submission'.

The problem I am having is I can not think of any way to effectively iterate and compile this data. I cannot join the rows from the tables because there can be 5 pages or multiple users from the same submission that have the same column names.

What I'm looking for is being able to create atleast a part of this theoretical JSON output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "pages": {
            "avgloadtime": "5",
            "avgclicks": "20",
            "pagesdata": {
                "index.php": {
                    "avg access time": "2"
                },
                "example.php": {
                    "avg access time": "2"
                },
                "contact.php": {
                    "avg access time": "2"
                },
                "help.php": {
                    "avg access time": "2"
                }
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "likespiecount": "500",
            "most_liked_users": [
                "george",
                "cindy",
                "overtonstackflow"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I understand this can be better done in a database such as couchDB, but I thought I'd give SQL a good try due to its feasibility for my users to find.

Comment: JSON is something of an anathema to SQL databases, meaning it doesn't play friendly with SQL.

Comment: There's nothing really special about JSON in itself for that, what I'm trying to do can be done in any form of data storage, the problem being that its not a simple 1 row = 1 submission.